# Rule of Product when choosing multiple items from sets

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you have 4 sets, $S_{1}, S_{2}, S_{3}, S_{4}$ and you want to find out how many ways you can select a combination of A items from set 1, B number of items from set 2, C from set 3 and D from set 4.

If you're choosing one item from each set, due to the Rule of Product it's just
$|S_{1}|\times|S_{2}|\times|S_{3}|\times|S_{4}|$

But what if you're selecting a different number of items from each set? My intuition tells me it should be:

${|S_{1}| \choose A}\times{|S_{2}| \choose B}\times{|S_{3}| \choose C}\times{|S_{4}| \choose D}$

An example would be picking a starting XI for a football (soccer) team. If you have 5 keepers, 10 defenders, 10 midfielders and 10 attackers to choose from and you want to pick 1, 4, 4, and 2 of those respectively, you would get:

${5 \choose 1}\times{10 \choose 4}\times{10 \choose 4}\times{10 \choose 2} = 5\times210\times210\times45=9922500$ combinations

Is it that simple?

Comment: Yes you are right